# Is there any fix for bootstrap 3 android issues with collapsed drop downs?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm testing with a samsung galaxy 3S. Even the demo on the Twitter Bootstrap 3 site for collapsed drop menus is buggy. I searched and found fixes for older versions of Bootstrap but nothing for 3. Kind of defeats the whole mobile first approach.

Comment: Buggy in what way? In what browser? I can view their demo in Chrome on my Galaxy S4 without issue. Do you have a more specific problem that you're encountering? If not maybe a post in the bootstrap issues tracker is a better idea? https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues

Comment: Default browser on Android 4.1.2. Thanks, I'll post something in the bootsrap issue tracker.